# Numpy not found after installation

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5

I just installed numpy on my PC (running windows 10, running python 3.5.2) using WinPython, but when i try to import it in IDLE with:   `import numpy` I get the ImportError: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\Desktop\DATA\dataScience1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'`.

Did I possibly install it incorrectly, or do I need to do something else before it can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux and Mac OS systems we can install modules directly by mentioning

```
pip install modulename (or) sudo pip install modulename
```

in terminal or command prompt.

But in windows we should mention location of python folder in c directory like c:\python3 and later we should use

```
pip install modulename
```

in command prompt or terminal.

or

go n check whether numpy module is installed in sitepackages of python 3 folder in c directory or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Support for Python 3 was added in NumPy version 1.5.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files//NumPy/1.5.0/NOTES.txt/view), so to begin with, you must download/install a newer version of NumPy.

or use this command to install numpy. This will install the latest version of numpy.

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Winpython has two size, and the smallest "Zero" size doesn't include numpy